# different tag different stylesheet

Tags: template-tags

i have tags, and for some tags i want to load a different stylesheet
But i don't know how

i have....

```
function customstyles()
{
    if ( is_tag( 'circulair' ) ) {

        //Register and enqueue the stylesheet for tag-circulair.
        wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair' );  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'tag-circulair' );

    } else {

        //Register and enqueue the default stylesheet.    
        wp_register_style( 'styles', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'styles' );  

    }   
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customstyles' );
```

But it won't do

Thanks Bets

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do instead is to get the tag in the header file of the theme and add the tag name as a class to one of the highest elements, for example .

That way, you can have a page tagged with "james", and say:

```
body.james #mainmenu li > a { color: #f00; }
```

Otherwise, you could get the tag and use php to try and load a stylesheet with the same name as the tag(or use a standard stylesheet if there are no tags, or file doesn't exist).

```
<?php
// Get the tags.
$tag = get_the_tags();
// Count the number of tags.
$count = count($tag);

// Check if there are tags at all.
if($tag != null) {
    $dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/";

    // Go through each tag.
    foreach($tag as $t) {
        // Get the full path to the CSS file we want to load based on the tag.
        $fullpath = $dir . $t->name . ".css";

        // Check if the file exists.
        if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
            // Link the CSS file.
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $fullpath . "' type='text/css'>";
        } else if($tag == $count) {
            // If not, link the standard CSS file, but only if on the last loop.
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='generic-stylesheet.css' type='text/css'>";
        }
    }
} ?>
```

That should do the trick. This should go in your theme's/child theme's header file, after all the other CSS files have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but the css file is to big to load in the header

Comment: Why is it too big to load in the header?

Comment: You right, is't not to big but it is to complicated because i have to do that for every tag that needs a different styleheet isn't it? And when i use php in the function, than it's easier. But i don't know how :)

Comment: Using the second solution in my answer, you wouldn't need to do much manually. Basically: 

get tagname -> find tagname.css -> if exist, load / else load standard.css

Comment: This seems very simple Magnus  do i write that code in function? and how do i write that?

Comment: Edited my answer with the full(but untested) code. :)

Comment: Keep in mind, this will try to locate and load multiple CSS files if you have multiple tags on your post. Which may or may not be what you want. (For example, if you have both one set of stylesheets for shapes and another set for colours.)

Comment: sorry it won't work Magnus i get a error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /header.php on line 60

Comment: Yeah, my bad! I forgot to specify that we wanted the name of the tag ($t->name), and shouldn't have used the $count variable for the "if()".

It works now. I've tested it. :)

Comment: hee Magnus i tested it but it won't work unfortunately. i tried several times, when the site is loading it takes a while when showing up, sorry thanks for your patience

Comment: No problems. Where are you adding the code?

Comment: first in the header and i tried it in  the function.php i tried the full path ..../wp-content/themes/customizr-child//css/circulair.css"

Comment: Ah, you don't need to add the full path, yourself. It automatically finds it through "get_stylesheet_directory()". :)

It should go in your header.php file. It won't work in functions.php because it's not a function.

Comment: okee i changed that  and i put everything after the last line but before the </header> and it seems, when i look at the page source there is no code.... so i think there is nothing been load

Comment: The only code that should show is the <link rel='stylesheet' href='/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/css/circulair.css' type='text/css'>, and only if the post has been tagged with "circulair".

The rest of the code will not show when viewing the source.

Comment: I think that i do the loading thing not correct, because the code (<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/css/circulair.css' type='text/css'>)don't show up

Comment: Have you put a tag on the post?

Comment: sorry for my late answer, yes i did put the tag on the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **has_tag** for it.

```
function customstyles() { 
  if ( has_tag( 'circulair' ) ) {
    //Register and enqueue the stylesheet for tag-circulair.
    wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair/style.css' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tag-circulair' );
  } else {
    //Register and enqueue the default stylesheet.    
    wp_register_style( 'styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles' );  
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customstyles' );
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your idea

the one that does the trick is

function register_tag_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair.css' );
 wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair-kantoor-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair.css' );

 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_tag_styles' );

Answer (score 0):

```
function register_tag_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'tag-circulair-kantoor-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout-circulair.css' );
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_tag_styles' );
```

This code does the trick for me, but i think it's too complicated when i have more than 10 tags with different stylesheets.....